# Keeping instantiated grid in the centre of the screen?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, alignment, center

everyone, I'm making a mobile game and I need help.
In the game, I instantiate a grid of dots as seen in the first attached file below.My problem is the grid is not in the centre of the screen
I could just position my main camera so the grid is in the centre the only problem with this approach being that the grid changes in size depending on your level as shown in attachment 2

here's my spawn code

```
        for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++)
            {
                SpawnDelay = Random.Range(0.2f, 0.5f);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(SpawnDelay);
                Instantiate(Dot, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                               NumberOfdots++;
                transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + distanceBetween, transform.position.y);

                if (y % MutpleNum == ByMutpleNum)
                {
                    transform.position = new Vector2(GridoffsetX/2, transform.position.y + GridoffsetY);
                }
            }
        }
        hasFinshedSpawning = true;
        StopCoroutine("CreateLevelY");
    }

    public void ResetObject() {

        transform.position = new Vector2(GridoffsetX/2, 1);


        ExpandGrid();

    }
```

Is there anyway I can have the grid centre regardless of its size

Thanks,

David

PS. it's possible I'm just missing a simple solution :)

Grid 1:

[image: Grid 1]

Grid 2:

[image: Grid 2]